# scheduled task onlogon repeat

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I need to set a Windows scheduled task that runs at logon and repeats at a given interval (say hourly for this case).

Basically, I want to do this via command line: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19514611/Capture.PNG

Microsoft's schtasks.exe page (found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  seems to imply you can't set any repetition for an ONLOGON event via command line, but can via the wizard.  Is this accurate?

EDIT:

After further research, I've found that I can export this configuration as an XML and build the task using the xml.  Is this the way I should go about this?  It will require something to parse out and generate a new xml file for each user (less than ideal) and I'd much rather do this via command line.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this thread is old but recently ran into the same issue.  The trick is to run a change command after the initial create command.  The following will change the task to run every 1 minute.

```
SCHTASKS.exe /Create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Your Task Name" /TR "c:\path\executableoftask.exe" /RU SomeUser /RP SomePassword

SCHTASKS.exe /Change /RI 1 /TN "Your Task Name" /RU SomeUser /RP SomePassword
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /U username /P password /SC ONLOGON /TN "Your Task Name" /TR c:\path\executableoftask.exe /RI HOURLY
```

Comment: When I try this on Windows 7, I get the message that the /RI flag is not applicable for ONLOGON schedule type